# How to load the map from our current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to load the map from my current location. Now I am using the following code.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }
```

After load the map

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MapsActivity.this);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);      
        if(checkLocationService()){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
```

Here the map showing the default location first after getting location the camera position moved to current location. But I want to load the map from my current location. Like UBER,OLA.. Please let me any idea to achieve my requirement.

Comment: You can't load the current location before the Location service received update. Uber does not do this, it waits for current location or it will use the last known location.

Comment: What you can do though, is only display the map after you have received a Location update.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for location to change first, then call the Google maps activity / load map.

```
private void requestLocation(){
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener
    );
}

private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Call maps activity here / load map
    }
};
```

You could also navigate to the middle of the ocean & display `waiting for location` message, wait for location update, then navigate back to current location. This is commonly used in apps that utilise maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the distance from your base location to the fetched current location, If it is under some meteres you can populate the map.

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

```
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {


         mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }
    }
}
```